# Spark2 Zeppelin interpreter dependency results in Null pointer NullPointerException

Tags: apache-spark, dependency-management, hadoop2, apache-zeppelin, apache-spark-2.0

I am trying to add dependency to Spark2 interpreter in Zeppelin as follows:

```
 org.bdgenomics.adam:adam-core-spark2_2.11:0.23.0
```

[image]

- There are no jars at localRepo location. So after I add this
  dependency and run a simple command like `println("hello world")` I
  am getting this NullPointerException:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:861)
>         at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
>         at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:493)
>         at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
>         at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

- Now there are a lot of packages with jars in `local-repo` folder and
  also under `local-repo/2C4U48MY3_spark2` which is the location for
  parameter `zeppelin.interpreter.localRepo`.

Here is zeppelin spark2 interpreter log: http://pasted.co/06cbc12a

Without this dependency, everything works fine.

I'm unable to say why I am getting this NPE. Can you help me please?